# Switching tab using conemu GuiMacro Tab() function does not work

Tags: tabs, macros, conemu

I have the following conemu GuiMacro's defined

```
<F9>   - Tab(3)
<F10>  - Tab(2)
```

When I press the keys, I see the previous/next tab being highlighted in the tab bar, but the highlighted tab is not being activated - i.e. keyboard input remains in the current tab. I want F10 & F9 to work like CtrlTab and CtrlShiftTab - i.e. the contents of the new tab should be shown and it should receive keyboard input. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the Tab() GuiMacro function does what it's supposed to. Looks like there is a distinction between Tab and Console in ConEmu. To do what I want you need to switch console, not tab.

There is a simple workaround. Simply map F9 and F10 to the `Switch next console` and `Switch previous console` `User hotkeys`.

Comment: you are a life saver